# ajax POST cross domain, .NET preview functionality

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, cross-domain

Looking for some advice on the correct approach and/or help on my current error.

I'm building two separate MVC3 apps: the admin and front-end of a data-driven site. The admin will eventually live in a sub-domain of the front-end.

As one of my requirements I have to build preview functionality into the admin. A user edits a profile or whatever and wants to see their changes without actually saving them.

So first, anyone have a suggested approach to displaying a page from the front-end with data from the back-end?

Second, my approach and the error I get:

First, when a user clicks preview in the admin app serialize the form and post it to a controller action in the front-end:

```
<script>
$("#previewPost").click(function () {
     $.ajax({
           async: false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:51569/Home/PreviewIndex',
            data: $("form").serialize(),
            dataType: 'html',
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function (data) {
                var popup = window.open();
                //popup.document.write(data);
            }
            ,
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                alert('error: ' + data);
            }
        });

});
```

In the controller I take the passed model, adjust it to match what the front-end expects then return it.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PreviewHome(CurationAdminHomeEditModel postedModel)
    {
         ...some stuff populating the model...
        return View("PreviewHome", retModel);
    }
```

Eventually the goal is to take that response and write it to a new window.

But it doesn't get that far. My initial POST works fine, I get to the controller action and send out the response. I can step through the return view and see it getting populated. But once that response gets fed back to my jquery result it comes through as an error, with this detail:

```
[Exception... "Failure"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS 
frame :: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js :: 
<TOP_LEVEL> :: line 4"  data: no]
```

So, any thoughts?

**EDIT**
Per discussion below with Kevin I have also added this to each app's web.config:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
```

I still get the same response in Firefox, running in Chrome gives me this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:51569/Home/PreviewIndex?. Origin localhost:51566 is >not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

**Edit 2 - psuedo-solution**

Still unclear on what caused this but I can make it work by just actually posting back the form (no ajax). So I'm going with that for now (though it means not popping a new window). If anyone has some brilliance to add I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: you can't post cross-domain unless your cross-domain server is returning proper CORS headers. Also, the `crossDomain` option isn't needed unless you intend to make a same-domain request act like a cross-domain request.

Comment: Kevin- I enabled CORS headers as described here (http://enable-cors.org/) to no effect. Anything else I should be doing?

Comment: Have you cross-browser tested it? some versions of IE have issues with CORS requests and require a jquery plugin.

Comment: I'm testing in FF, will try chrome in a sec... to be clear though, my initial POST works. I get to the controller action in the front-end site and everything appears happy as I return my action result. It's just the actual response that doesn't seem to go through.

Comment: Chrome has the same result, but is giving me a better error message... but confusing since both configs are setup to allow the access: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:51569/Home/PreviewIndex?. Origin http://localhost:51566 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Just tried pulling it out of the ajax call and just submitting the form with a postback. That works.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? (not that i know of one that doesn't work with it.)